# rdf:collection in sparql

Tags: collections, rdf, sparql, semantic-web

I have in an RDF file an `rdf:collection`. When I have a collection of one author the following query returns nothing.  However, the query works for two or more authors, but only returns two authors. What can I do to write out all authors?

```xml
<bibo:authorList rdf:parseType="Collection">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://openlibrary.org/authors/OL113143A"/>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://openlibrary.org/authors/OL6784959A"/>
</bibo:authorList>
```

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

select ?title ?author ?author2
where { 
  ?x dc:title ?title . 

  ?x bibo:authorList ?object.
  ?object rdf:first ?name. 
  ?name rdf:value ?author.

  ?object rdf:rest ?object2.
  ?object2 rdf:first ?name2.
  ?name2 rdf:value ?author2 . 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is that you are trying to something semi-recursive so your results vary depending on the length of the RDF list. The query as written will only work for lists of length 2 or more, lists of length 1 won't work due to the fact the second portion of your query will have nothing to match.

If you want to access a collection the best way is with a property path like so (requires SPARQL 1.1):

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  ?list rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?member .
}
```

You can adapt this general pattern to fit into your query as you see fit.

Comment: use ARC2 for SPARQL queries for me so I do not have such a request. Wrote somewhere: ARC2 does not support SPARQL 1.1 's subqueries. How to create a query with SPARQL 1.0? How to install in the ARC2 SPARQL 1.1? –

Comment: @Magdalena ARC2 does not support SPARQL 1.1 so you cannot use this query if you are using ARC2

Comment: What to use instead of your collection? Arc2 would I need and I need something that will replace my collections.